# Should I make an IBOutlets for objects in nib?

Tags: ios

Is anybody know, how nib controls is deallocated if they has no IBOutlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything in a nib that is not at the top level (e.g. a button inside a view) and has no outlet will be deallocated when the superview is deallocated.

In an ARC project outlets should be weak anyway, so they will revert to nil when the superview is deallocated.

You don't need outlets just for the purpose of deallocation.